# How to set request data in controller

Tags: cakephp

I have to set request data which is in the form of HTML in **CAKEPHP**.
Request Data is :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <h3>Company Name</h3>
            Company Address
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <h5>INVOICE</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How to set this in controller? $this->set() is not working.

```
$this->set('html', $this->request->data);
```

View :-

```
<?php echo $html; ?>
```

Comment: That is not valid request data. What exactly are you trying to send to the view? The company information? Ellaborate on `$this->set();` is not working.

Comment: Html doesn't belong in the controller, it should be in the View

Comment: I have to set html in the view.but how?

Answer (score 2):

In case you are talking about data to fill form

```
$this->request->data = $this->YourModel->find();
```

should do the trick.